# Update smart group counts errors with syntax error (AND instead of WHERE in sql)

Tags: smartgroups

This is a bit of a corner case.  This is reproduced in http://d46.demo.civicrm.org.

Go to Contacts => Manage Groups

Click on Update Smart Group Counts (left side below the Find Groups box)

It will error with a syntax error.  It errors on the smart group LYBUNT.

This smart group was created with Search => Custom Searches => Contributions made in Year X and not Year Y.

Comment: If you can replicate this on the demo site, and you're getting an error, then you've found a bug.  You can report it via the issue queue (https://civicrm.org/issue-queue).  Note that it's unlikely to be fixed without submitting to the paid issue queue (https://civicrm.org/paid-issue-queue) or submitting a patch!

Comment: Yea, I guess I really should have and I will.    This was an offshoot of another one.  Monish Deb asked me to create a new one.  Same error different cause.  He fixed the other case.  Generating dynamic sql and getting all the clauses just right is an art.

Comment: Created issue CRM-16931 for this.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but it seems if there is a Smart Group that has no contacts it will throw up an error, at least, it does in my instance. I just disabled that Smart Group and the Update link doesn't throw a syntax error any more.